# ASP.NET Core MVC partialview

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Why partial view gets after scripts?

Any help would be appreciated. I think that there is a problem with the script. But what is not.

Controller

```
public ActionResult EditContract(int id)
{
    var contracts = _context.Contract.Find(id);
    ViewData["CustomersId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers, "Id", "Name",   ontracts.CustomersId);
    return PartialView(contracts);
}
```

Index.chtml

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditCustomer">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h4><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Edit Customer</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="myEditCustomer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function EditCustomer(id) {
        var url = "/Customers/EditCustomer?id=" + id;
        $("#myEditCustomer").load(url, function () {
            $("#EditCustomer").modal("show");
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, we can find that you make request(s) with the url `/Customers/EditCustomer` on JavaScript client side, but the name of your action is `EditContract`, please make sure you make request with the correct url, or you can configure routing for your action, like below.

```
[Route("Customers/EditCustomer")]
public ActionResult EditContract(int id)
{
```

> Why partial view gets after scripts?

You are using [jQuery .load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method to dynamically get partial view result from server and populate it to div container `"modal-body"` rather than directly [using Tag Helper/HTML Helper to reference your partial view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-a-partial-view-in-a-markup-file) in view page, so your partial view would be displayed/rendered after you called JavaScript function.